# Form mail not supporting latin characters

Tags: php, forms, utf-8

I can not get the email that my (image)upload form is sending, to support latin characters.

```
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed\n" .
                  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


      $message ="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
      $message.="--{$mime_boundary}\n";
      $message.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
      $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
```

Any thoughts?

Sorry for the thin content, would this be more helpful?

```
    $fileatt      = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
    $fileatt_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
    $fileatt_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];


    $headers = "From: $emailfrom";


      $semi_rand = md5(time());
      $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";



      $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed\n" .
                  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";




      $subject='Presentación de la fotografía';

      $message ="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
      $message.="--{$mime_boundary}\n";
      $message.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
      $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
      $message.="".$namefrom." nos envía este foto.<br />\n\n";

    if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
      // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
      $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
      $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
      fclose($file);

      // Base64 encode the file data
      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));


      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                  //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                  $data . "\n\n" .
                  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
    }


    $envs = array("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "REMOTE_ADDR", "REMOTE_HOST");
    foreach ($envs as $env)
    $message .= "$env: $_SERVER[$env]\n";

    if(!mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
        exit("Disculpa se ha producido un error. Inténtalo de nuevo. Gracias<");
    } else {
        echo '<div id="formfeedback">'. $thanksmessage .'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['myForm']);
        print_form();

    }
```

Curiously when I receive my test mails on my mac I get invalid character but on my iPhone is shows correctly.

Comment: "to support latin characters"?You really mean in your attemts none of the latin characters are supported?

Comment: I fail to connect the term "the email that my (image)upload form is sending" with the snippets you give. If that snippet is php code that evaluates an upload form being submitted then what has the term email to do with that? If you use a form with method "email", then where do these lines come into play?

Comment: In short: you have to give much more information if you want any help in this.

Comment: don't build your own mime messages. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. they'll do it far easier and with far less code.

Answer (score 0):

Use charset ISO-8859-1. It has support to Western European, Latin-1. UTF-8 is ASCII compatible multi-byte 8-bit Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

The following nailed it

in the form: `$message.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";`
in the html: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

The only thing I actually changed was (in the html meta) UTF-8 into capital letters.